# On Ptolemy climes

Tags: middle-ages, geography, ptolemy, antiquity

Reading Dante's *Comedy*, I was interested in understand a little bit how medieval geography worked, so I decided to have a look at
Edward Luther Stevenson's translation of Ptolemy's *Geographia*. I've also read the review of this book that Audrey Diller wrote in 1935, so I know it's not precisely the best translation of Ptolemy's work, but it's better than nothing.

In particular, in the XXVII *canto* of the *Paradiso*, Dante mentions the first clime, so I was curious to understand what climes exactly were.

Comparing the explanation of parallels used in the delineation of maps and the reproduction of maps that are at the end of the book, which in fact are not the maps of Ptolemy, but the 27 Ptolemaic maps as revised by Donnus Nicolaus Germanus in the XV century (in particular, they are designed using a different projection), I have seen the following:

- The first clime is located on the parallel through the Meroe island.
- The second clime is located on the parallel through Syene.
- The third clime is located on the parallel with a latitude of 30° 20'.
- The fourth clime is located on the parallel drawn through Rhodes.
- The fifth clime is located on the parallel with a latitude of 40° 55'.
- The sixth clime is located on the parallel with a latitude of 45°.
- The seventh clime is located on the parallel with a latitude of 48° 30'.

I've also read that the part of the earth that was considered as inhabited by humans was bounded on the south by a land which was unknown which encompasses some part of Africa and the Indian Ocean (the "Indian sea" at that time). To delineate maps, the southern boundary of the inhabited earth was defined by the parallel that has a latitude of 16° 25' south of the equator. Now, my question is: was this parallel considered the southern limit of the first clime?

At this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbw4jjz9lotoih7/carta_limite_sud_africa_quattrocento.pdf?dl=0) you will find the Latin inscription on such parallel on the map of Africa: I can't understand what it says.

**Update:**

I've found this illustration in the book, but I have no idea where it comes from, but I think it's probably from the Renaissance, since the source of Stevenson's work seems to be Renaissance Latin translations of the *Geographia*:

[image]

So I now suspect that the southern limit of the first clime was the equator and that the parallel with a latitude of 16° 25' south of the equator was defined  at Renaissance (?) as the Antidiameroes, that is, the boundary of some kind of first clime in the southern hemisphere. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe useful: [Ptolemy's Geography: An Annotated Translation of the Theoretical Chapters](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Ptolemy_s_Geography/72zdDwAAQBAJ)

Comment: See [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_world_map#/media/File:PtolemyWorldMap.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, @MauroALLEGRANZA, but I cannot buy such an expensive book.

Comment: Libraries are useful. Have a look here (putting in your own location): https://www.worldcat.org/title/ptolemys-geography-an-annotated-translation-of-the-theoretical-chapters/oclc/1156058314

Comment: OK, thanks, but I believe that Ptolemy's climes are described in *Almagest* and not in *Geographia*. In Stevenson's translation there is no trace of them.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: This map is from XV century Jacobus Angelus's translation. A similar map is reproduced in my book.

Comment: My copy is the Oxford World's Classics edition, translated by Sisson.  In the commentary on Canto XXVII Sisson writes of the *first clime* :  "*It embraced the eastern and western extremities of the known land-mass in the Northern Hemi-sphere, from the Ganges to Spain, with Jerusalem in the middle, an arc of 180 degrees.*"  Dante's vantage point at the time is given as firstly the meridian at Jerusalem and secondly at the meridian at Cadiz.

Comment: According to [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://en.google-info.org/1899033/1/clime.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clime), only Aristotle's system of five climes included a uninhabitable equatorial zone.  Aristotle's five climes covered the globe.  Ptolemy's original system of 39 climes started at the equator and proceeded north only.  Ptolemy reduced his system firstly to 11 climes and then finally to the 7 climes you have specified, always limiting his system to the northern hemisphere.  Europeans preferred Aristotle's system, so I would guess Dante did too.

Comment: The quote I gave from the commentary to Sisson's translation suggests that Dante is using Aristotle's system rather than Ptolemy's.

Comment: @Nick:   I own three different editions of *Paradiso* (in Italian) and the notes of all of them mention seven climes, so I suppose they are essentially those of Ptolemy. The entire longitude of habitable earth is said to be in his *Geographia* of 180°, locating the Fortunate Islands (Canary Islands, essentially Spain) at the extreme west (0°) and the metropolis of Sina (India) at the extreme east (180°). Hierosolyma or Aelia Capitolia (Jerusalem) has a longitude of 66° 31' 40" (this is certainly different from Dante).

Answer (score 5):

Originally, the Greek word κλῐ́μᾰ means “slope, incline, inclination,” and has nothing to do with the modern meaning of the word (long-term weather). Ptolemy defined the seven *climata* by the length of the longest duration for the day (defined as the period when the sun is visible in the sky, and as opposed to night, when it’s not visible; the combination of both day and night periods [24 hours] is a *nycthemera*).

One clima differs from the next by a half-hour of day per nycthemera. The map you link to does have mentions of the duration of the day: for example, the second line from the bottom says “3[?] paral[x] habet maximũ diem hora[x] 12½¼” (where the [?] means I’m not sure it’s a 3; the [x]s are characters I can’t reproduce; and ½¼ is to be read as ½ + ¼ = ¾).

Ptolemy believed that the equatorial regions of the Earth were too hot to be inhabited, so he counted only “habitable” climata. The first one, as you pointed out, is the parallel of Meroe, where the longest day (June solstice) lasts 13 hours. Then for Syene, the longest day would last 13½ hours, and so on, until the clima of the Borysthenes (modern Dniepr river in Ukraine) at 48° 32′ and a longest daytime of 16 hours.

As for the mention of climata in the works of later authors, most of them, if not all, do indeed correspond to the Ptolemaic climata.